# usb drive is not mounting

Tags: usb-drive

I have a sony usb drive of 8 gb. It is not mounting at all. Help me mount it. It seems like there is some problem with my usb. The following is the `disks` window of my window.

[image: disks window]

---

**Additional Details:**

- Drive not showing up in GParted
- `fdisk: unable to open /dev/sdd: No medium found` is the output for the command `sudo fdisk /dev/sdd`. I thought that formatting it would help me. It didn't.

Comment: Can you take a screen shot of this in GParted ?

Comment: @Neil: Drive not showing up in GParted.